# After add the Group by clause return nothing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, and I have `Table1` which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    [DTAMID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LayoutName] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Content] [VARCHAR](100) NULL
)
```

This is the sample data I have:

```
DTAMID LayoutName       Content
-------------------------------------
1      Layout 1         Content 1
2      LayoutName1      Test1
3      LayoutName1      Test11
4      LayoutName1      PQR
```

When I run this query

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(COUNT(DTAMID), 0)
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    LayoutName = RTRIM(LTRIM('layout1'))
    AND Content = RTRIM(LTRIM('test221'))
GROUP BY
    DTAMID
```

I expected 0 for the output of this query - but it is return nothing. Can anyone explain this please?

Answer (score 4):

Take off your ISNULL and remove your group by. That should get you the result you want.

```
Select Count(DTAMID)
From table1
Where rtrim(ltrim(LayoutName)) = 'layout1' and  
      rtrim(ltrim(Content)) = 'test221';
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your WHERE clause you are returning Zero records.

You are expecting to return 1 Record that contains a NULL.

According to SQL, NULL is still a value, SQL just doesn't know what the value is, it's a bit like schrodinger's cat.

NULL is not "nothing", it's an "Unknown".